# How to dump Bugsnag report in Ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, rack, bugsnag

I would like to dump the complete report sent to Bugsnag in Ruby.

I tried this:

```
Bugsnag.before_notify_callbacks << lambda {|report|
     puts report
}
```

But the only result I get is the following:

```
#<Bugsnag::Report:0x000055d8ab22f310>
```

I also tried `puts report.to_json` with (`require 'json'` of course), same result.

I would like to get a json-like dump of the report that is being sent, something like:

```
stacktrace: "..."
app: {
        releaseStage: "..."
        ...
     }
request: {
     ....
}
my-custom-tag: {
    ...
}
```

The exact format does not matter, the only important thing is that I'm able to see all the fields. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-ruby/blob/master/lib/bugsnag/report.rb) of that gem it looks like there is the [`Report#as_json`](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-ruby/blob/master/lib/bugsnag/report.rb#L90) that returns what you are looking for.

```
Bugsnag.before_notify_callbacks << lambda { |report|
  puts report.as_json
}
```